# I installed yarn globally, but got error "zsh:command not found : yarn"

Tags: npm, zsh, yarnpkg

```
npm install -g yarn

> yarn@1.22.15 preinstall /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)

/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/yarn -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
    /Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/yarnpkg -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
    + yarn@1.22.15
```

As I use a mac, I opened the zshrc file.
and then write the code below

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/yarn
```

However, when I entered the yarn --v command, I got the same error as the title.

Could you please tell me what the problem is? What should I do when I have installed a variable globally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the global [npm bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-bin) to `PATH` instead:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(npm bin -g)"
```

In your case, this is the same as:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me on the Mac OS  Monterey 12.3.1

```
npm install -g yarn
npm config get prefix
```

My command output was:  `/Users/my_username/.npm-packages`

Append that in your */etc/paths* using nano

Open up Terminal.

Run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

Enter your password, when prompted.

Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the path you wish to add.

Hit control-x to quit.

Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.

That’s it!  To test it, in new terminal window, type:

```
echo $PATH
```

You will see `/Users/my_username/.npm-packages/bin` appended to your path

Yarn should now work

```
yarn --version
```

You will see `2.4.x`